# Adding/removing User Controls on Canvas in WPF

Tags: wpf, canvas, user-controls

I have created two WPF user controls having multiple textboxes, comboboxes and buttons. In the main wpf window, I have created a Canvas and a listbox with two listitems in it. My requirement is, if select the first listbox item, the first user control should get added to canvas. If I select the second listbox item, the previously added user control should get hide, and second one should get added/showed. Can anyone provide an expample for this code?

Below is code I have writtent.I have created two user controls.

**UserControl1.xaml**

```
    <UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Width="210" Height="210" x:Name="UCntl1">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
        <GroupBox Header="Text Boxes">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Margin="4" Height="21">TextBox1</Label>
                    <Label Margin="4" Height="21">TextBox2</Label>
                    <Label Margin="4" Height="21">TextBox3</Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Width="100" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4">0.1</TextBox>
                    <TextBox Width="100" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4">0.2</TextBox>
                    <TextBox Width="100" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4">0.3</TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Header="Conbo Boxes">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Margin="4" Height="21">ComboBox1</Label>
                        <Label Margin="4" Height="21">ComboBox2</Label>
                        <Label Margin="4" Height="21">ComboBox3</Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ComboBox Width="100" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4">
                            <ComboBoxItem>Item AAA</ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>
                        <ComboBox Width="100" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4">
                            <ComboBoxItem>Item BBB</ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>
                        <ComboBox Width="100" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4">
                            <ComboBoxItem>Item CCC</ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl2.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl2"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Width="210" Height="210" x:Name="UCntl2">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <GroupBox Header="Conbo Boxes">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Margin="4" Height="21">ComboBox1</Label>
                    <Label Margin="4" Height="21">ComboBox2</Label>
                    <Label Margin="4" Height="21">ComboBox3</Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel>
                    <ComboBox Width="100" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"></ComboBox>
                    <ComboBox Width="100" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"></ComboBox>
                    <ComboBox Width="100" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"></ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Header="Text Boxes">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Margin="4" Height="21">TextBox1</Label>
                    <Label Margin="4" Height="21">TextBox2</Label>
                    <Label Margin="4" Height="21">TextBox3</Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Width="100" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Width="100" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Width="100" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Window1.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListBox Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="White">
                <ListBoxItem Name="LstItem1" Selected="LstItem1_Selected">User Control 1</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="LstItem2" Selected="LstItem2_Selected">User Control 2</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Width="10" Background="LightGray"></Grid>
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Canvas Name="Canvas1" Width="210" Height="210" VerticalAlignment="Top">

            </Canvas>
        </Grid>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Widow1.xaml.vb**

```
Class Window1 

Private Sub LstItem1_Selected(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Canvas1.Children.Clear()
    Canvas1.Children.Add(New UserControl1)
End Sub

Private Sub LstItem2_Selected(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Canvas1.Children.Clear()
    Canvas1.Children.Add(New UserControl2)
End Sub
```

End Class

**Problem**

I have added the user control after removing the previous controls in the canvas. Because of this the selected values in the list boxes in UserControls are getting cleared while re-adding the control to the canvas. Is there any method to hide the usercontrols on the canvas, instead of removing the controls from canvas.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started. It's not exactly how I'd do it in a real project, but close enough. I wish there was an easy way to attach projects to answers on this site.

The end result looks like this:

[image]
[image]

**App.xaml**:

```
<Application x:Class="SO9735486.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SO9735486.ViewModels"
             xmlns:v="clr-namespace:SO9735486.Views"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MainViewModel}">
            <v:MainView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FirstContentViewModel}">
            <v:FirstContentView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SecondContentViewModel}">
            <v:SecondContentView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="SO9735486.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
namespace SO9735486
{
    using System.Windows;
    using SO9735486.ViewModels;

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Content = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**:

```
namespace SO9735486.ViewModels
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Threading;

    // http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/04/mvvm-infrastructure-viewmodel.html
    public abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;

        protected ViewModel()
        {
            if (Application.Current != null)
            {
                _dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
            }
            else
            {
                //this is useful for unit tests where there is no application running
                _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            }

        }

        [field: NonSerialized]
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected Dispatcher Dispatcher
        {
            get { return _dispatcher; }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentViewModel.cs**:

```
namespace SO9735486.ViewModels
{
    public abstract class ContentViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        private readonly string displayName;

        protected ContentViewModel(string displayName)
        {
            this.displayName = displayName;
        }

        public string DisplayName
        {
            get { return this.displayName; }
        }
    }
}
```

**FirstContentViewModel.cs**:

```
namespace SO9735486.ViewModels
{
    public sealed class FirstContentViewModel : ContentViewModel
    {
        private string name;

        public FirstContentViewModel()
            : base("First")
        {
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set
            {
                if (this.name != value)
                {
                    this.name = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondContentViewModel.cs**:

```
namespace SO9735486.ViewModels
{
    public sealed class SecondContentViewModel : ContentViewModel
    {
        public SecondContentViewModel()
            : base("Second")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**:

```
namespace SO9735486.ViewModels
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public sealed class MainViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        private readonly ICollection<ContentViewModel> contentViewModels;
        private ContentViewModel selectedContentViewModel;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.contentViewModels = new List<ContentViewModel>
            {
                new FirstContentViewModel(),
                new SecondContentViewModel()
            };

            this.selectedContentViewModel = this.contentViewModels.First();
        }

        public ICollection<ContentViewModel> ContentViewModels
        {
            get { return this.contentViewModels; }
        }

        public ContentViewModel SelectedContentViewModel
        {
            get { return this.selectedContentViewModel; }
            set
            {
                if (this.selectedContentViewModel != value)
                {
                    this.selectedContentViewModel = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedContentViewModel");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FirstContentView.xaml**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SO9735486.Views.FirstContentView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label>First Content View</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**SecondContentView.xaml**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SO9735486.Views.SecondContentView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label>Second content view</Label>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="100" Height="30"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**MainView.xaml**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SO9735486.Views.MainView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DockPanel>
        <ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ContentViewModels}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContentViewModel}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedContentViewModel}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Could you please see the above posted code in my question and reply me if you have any solution for this

Comment: Boogaart Thanks for looking into this. I got the answer. Instead of removing the controls from canvas (CanvasForm.Clear) I should set the visibilty of controls to Collapsed. I have posted this answer. As I am new to this area (WinForms and WPF), I don't know the visibilty property. Once again thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Changes done for Windows1.xaml.vb only. The code bhind file should be as below. The answer for the problem is instead of callinf Canvas1.Clear(), set the visibilty of the added user controls to Windows.Visibility.Collapsed.

**Window1.xaml.vb**

```
Class Window1 
Private U1 As Integer
Private U2 As Integer
Private Sub LstItem1_Selected(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Canvas1.Children.Item(U1).Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
    Canvas1.Children.Item(U2).Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
End Sub

Private Sub LstItem2_Selected(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Canvas1.Children.Item(U2).Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
    Canvas1.Children.Item(U1).Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
End Sub

Private Sub Window1_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    U1 = Canvas1.Children.Add(New UserControl1)
    U2 = Canvas1.Children.Add(New UserControl2)

    Canvas1.Children.Item(U1).Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
    Canvas1.Children.Item(U2).Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
End Sub
End Class
```