# Changing heavy UserControls in WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, optimization, user-controls

I have read a lot of subjects on the matter, on how to replace the displayed UserControl in WPF.
Suggestions tend towards Databinding of Content Control, and Kent Boggart answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735486/adding-removing-user-controls-on-canvas-in-wpf).

Anyways, the first problem is that my User Controls involve heavy graphical display, and are using common resources, not accessible at the same time.
What I mean by heavy graphics, on the `OtherControl`, there is a couple of videos plus a 3D model, reacting to dynamic events. The `BallControl` has an ellipse with TranslateAnimation, and a Margin reacting to events. I believe the whole project is a bit heavy due to the dynamic events rendering the pages.

So my solution was not ideal : I am clearing the content in the `Grid`, and replacing it with the needed User Control (the Grid takes the whole page).
The difference with the post above is that I would like (if possible) to keep my User Control as is.

The problem is that, these controls need to be switched very often, and after **1 or two hours using it, this Exception show up** (line specified in the code):

> System.ArgumentException : Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget class.
>
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)

My code is obvisously wrong and I wished a cleaner solution. What's more, I've understood that there is only one UI thread, and **pre-load already constructed Controls before diplaying them was not possible**.
To be more precise, a bit of code is more than welcome :

**MainWindow.xaml** :

```
<Window x:Class="Testing.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testing"
    xmlns:h="http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="1080" Width="1920" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" MinHeight="1080" MinWidth="1920" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Grid x:Name="Griddy">
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** :

```
    BallControl _boule;
    OtherControl _otherControl;
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;

       
        EventReceive.Subscribe(this);
        // Instanciate both UserControls
        _boule = new BallControl();
        _otherControl = new OtherControl();
        panelToDisplay = Turn.Ball;


        Griddy.Children.Add(boule);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event coming from panels to notify which one is to be displayed
    /// returning value is an Enum
    /// </summary>
    public void Receive<T>(T arg) where T : EventArgs
    {
        var casted = arg as EventArriving;
        if (casted != null)
        {
            PanelToDisplay = casted.TurningTable;
        }
    }


    private Turn panelToDisplay;
    public Turn PanelToDisplay
    {
        get { return panelToDisplay; }
        set 
        {
            if (panelToDisplay != value)
            {
                panelToDisplay = value;
                if (panelToDisplay == Turn.Other)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.Griddy.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => Griddy.Children.Add(_otherControl))); //Where the exception shows up
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());

                    }
                    try
                    {
                        this.Griddy.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => Griddy.Children.Remove(_boule)));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                         MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                    }
                    
                }
                if (panelToDisplay == Turn.Ball)
                {   // Bad Pattern where I remove a control to display another one.
                    try
                    {
                        this.Griddy.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => Griddy.Children.Add(_boule))); //Where the exception shows up
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        this.Griddy.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => Griddy.Children.Remove(_otherControl)));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```

To summarize a little :

- How do I replace/change/add & remove a User Control from the MainWindow in a clean way?
- How do I make it look like it doesn't have to load back up each time it changes, even when the controls are graphically heavy?

Comment: *"It crashes"* With what exception? On what line?

Comment: Actually in debug it never does, only when I test the .exe

Comment: I'd add some logic to catch the exception and display it in that case, it would be helpful to know what it is complaining about.

Comment: @RonBeyer You were absolutely right, please see my updated answer

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your usercontrol, and further explain what heavy loading you're doing here?

Comment: @HighCore I would love to be more precise, but the project belongs to my company and they want it under the radar for the moment. What I could tell you is that on the Other page, there is a couple of videos plus a 3D model reacting to a lot of events.
On the Ball page there is a simple ellipse but with Translate Animation and Margin movement reacting to events. Is it enough? In the meantime, I am adding these elements in the question.